# Create new FrameLayout on button click - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-framelayout

I'm trying to create a new FrameLayout each time I click a button. At the moment I've manually implemented 3 FrameLayouts and when I click the button all 3 are set to visible. All I want for now is for one FrameLayout to be set to visible, then if the button is clicked again, the second FrameLayout to appear etc.. The java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.viginti.MESSAGE";
    int hoursValue;
    int minutesValue;
    int finalMinutes;
    int finalHours;
    int correctDivision;
    int timeLeft;
    int twentyFour;
    int i, x;
    NumberPicker np_hours;
    NumberPicker np_minutes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

        fillArray();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );
        return true;
    }

    public void generateAnswer( View view ) {

        hoursValue = np_hours.getValue();
        minutesValue = np_minutes.getValue();

        try {
            twentyFour = 24;
            correctDivision = 10;
            finalMinutes = minutesValue / correctDivision;
            finalHours = twentyFour - hoursValue;
            timeLeft = finalHours - finalMinutes;
        } catch( NumberFormatException e ) {
            /** DEBUGGING */
            System.out.println( "Number Format Exception: " + e );
        }
        String finalResult = Integer.toString( timeLeft );
        Intent displayData = new Intent( this, DisplayData.class );
        displayData.putExtra( EXTRA_MESSAGE, finalResult );
        startActivity( displayData );
    }

    public void fillArray() {
        np_hours = ( NumberPicker ) findViewById( R.id.hourNumber );
        np_minutes = ( NumberPicker ) findViewById( R.id.minuteNumber );
        String[] hoursArray = new String[25];
        String[] minutesArray = new String[61];
        for( i = 0; i < hoursArray.length; i++ ) {
            hoursArray[i] = Integer.toString( i );
        }

        for( x = 0 ; x < minutesArray.length; x++ ){
            minutesArray[x] = Integer.toString( x );
        }
        np_hours.setMinValue( 0 );
        np_hours.setMaxValue( 24 );
        np_hours.setWrapSelectorWheel( false );
        np_hours.setDisplayedValues( hoursArray );

        np_minutes.setMinValue( 0 );
        np_minutes.setMaxValue( 60 );
        np_minutes.setWrapSelectorWheel( false );
        np_minutes.setDisplayedValues( minutesArray );
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void adActivity( View view ) {

        //Add first frame
        FrameLayout addActivities = ( FrameLayout )findViewById( R.id.frameLayout2 );
        addActivities.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

        //Add second frame
        FrameLayout addActivities1 = ( FrameLayout )findViewById( R.id.frameLayout3 );
        addActivities1.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        //Add third frame
        FrameLayout addActivities2 = ( FrameLayout )findViewById( R.id.frameLayout4 );
        addActivities2.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        fillArray();
    }
}
```

The XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/featuredimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="generateAnswer"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/generate_button" />

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/addActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="adActivity"
        android:src="@drawable/add_activity" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/plan"
                android:layout_width="121dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:entries="@array/daily_plans" />

            <NumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/hourNumber"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

            <NumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/minuteNumber"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:visibility="gone">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/plan1"
                android:layout_width="121dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:entries="@array/daily_plans" />

            <NumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/hourNumber"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

            <NumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/minuteNumber"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:visibility="gone">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/plan1"
                android:layout_width="121dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:entries="@array/daily_plans" />

            <NumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/hourNumber"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

            <NumberPicker
                android:id="@+id/minuteNumber"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout3"
            android:visibility="gone">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/plan1"
                    android:layout_width="121dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:entries="@array/daily_plans" />

                <NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/hourNumber"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"/>

                <NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/minuteNumber"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Worth mentioning that I'm fairly new to Android development. Also, if there is a better way of generating FrameLayouts each time the button is clicked (and positioning them correctly) I'd love to hear!

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: There may be a better way to create the effect you are working on. Why are you adding these to your layout?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your solution, if it does what you want it to.  In fact, I like your solution over adding widgets programmatically, because,

- You can position them where you want everything to go, and make it
  look good in the visual editor;
- You can use different resources (like styles, dimensions, layouts, and drawables) to make it look good on
  different screens;
- You can create a different layout for landscape and tablets;
- And meanwhile you can wire up the widgets in your code easily (since you have already given them an id in the XML file).

You may want to put it all in a scrollview, for situations where you can't make it fit on a small screen.

Comment: Thank's a lot! Yeah I found this much easier, I just need to get it to add a layout when the button is clicked (instead of all 3 i.e. 1 every time the button is clicked).